# Visualizing points with probability on an image as a heatmap

Tags: matlab, visualization, heatmap

I have a set of points stored in a variable called `pts`, which is a `Mx3` matrix.

Where `pts(:,1)` are the x coordinates on the image, `pts(:,2)` are the y coordinates on the image, and `pts(:,3)` are the probabilities.

How can I visualize the points on the image as a heatmap. Points with 
higher probabilities shown in dense red color. Similar to the image attached.

Any help would be much appreciated!

[image: See image for an example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the fact you didn't supply the data I cant use your example, but a simple solution to your problem is to use `imagesc` on top of your image with the `z` coordinate value as the color. you obviously should play with the transparency in order to get the desired result.

some simple example:

```
rgbImage = imread('p.jpg');

dims = size(rgbImage);
p = rand(dims(1),dims(1));

x = linspace(1,dims(1), dims(1));
y = linspace(1,dims(1), dims(1));
A = meshgrid(x,y);
size(A)

imagesc(rgbImage);
hold on
im = imagesc(x,y,p);
im.AlphaData = .5;
```

The original image is:

[image]

and after applying the script:

[image]

*NOTE*

I just add random noise but its easy to adapt to what you desire